# A value of type char[5] cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int[0]"

Tags: c

I am trying to add values to this array of strings in C after initializing it. I know I can do the easy method of just adding all the values in the array by adding it in {} but I wish to manually add them. Why am I getting a type error when i do this?

```
const char *built_in_commands[7];
built_in_commands[0] = "blah";
built_in_commands[1] = "hmm";
```

I have tried to use `strcopy` but that lead to the same error as well.

Comment: The code you have provided shouldn't produce that error.

Comment: Are you sure the error message in the title doesn't come from `const int *built_in_commands[7];` (`int` not `char`)? There is an obvious typo in `strcopy`, are there others? Please copy/paste an exact [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: The code provided can produce that error. See my answer. I do not see the exact wording OP reports from GCC and Clang on Compiler Explorer, but the wording does fit the nature of the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil has answered my question. I understand now why I am getting that error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil my mistake. Was thinking c++.

Answer (score 2):

You intend `built_in_commands[0] = "blah";` to be an executable statement. But you have put it outside of any function, so the compiler attempts to interpret it as a declaration.

It is not proper modern C, but to support old C programs, some compilers will assume a default `int` type, making it `int built_in_commands[0] = "blah";`. Then it is a declaration that attempts to declare a zero-length array and to initialize it with  `"blah"`. In other words, your code attempts to use `"blah"`, which has type `char [5]`, to initialize `builtin_commands`, which has type `int [0]`, and that explains the message you get from the compiler.

You could get this to work by putting `built_in_commands[0] = "blah";` and `built_in_commands[1] = "hmm";` inside `main`, so they will be executable statements executed at the start of the program.